# Realm.io : Persist an enum

Tags: ios, objective-c, realm

Given the following:

```
typedef NS_OPTIONS(NSUInteger, AssetClass)
{
    AssetClassFixed = 1,
    AssetClassPortable = 2
};
```

How can I define an entity that will persist itself with a property of the enum type?

```
@interface MyEntity : RLMObject

@property AssetClass assetClass;

@end
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is expected to fail with:

> 'Can't persist property 'assetClass' with incompatible type. Add to
>   ignoredPropertyNames: method to ignore.'

With **Objective-C** enumerations, the only reason that it doesn't work is, because the enum type is based on an unsigned type, which are [not yet supported](https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa/issues/651).

If you would change it to an signed type, it should work without the alias property.

```
-typedef NS_OPTIONS(NSUInteger, AssetClass)
+typedef NS_OPTIONS(NSInteger, AssetClass)
```